# Google web Toolkit with monorail

Tags: gwt, castle-monorail

Well the topic says it all. Can I use google web toolkit to generate my views to be used in Castle Monorail project and render it through nvelocity view engine. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anyone that has tried this, but GWT is a server-independent technology so in principle I don't see why it wouldn't work. GWT needs some [server-side plumbing](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) which you'll probably have to write yourself (again because I haven't found anyone that has done this before).

You might want to check out [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) which is similar to GWT but you code in .Net, it has MSBuild support, Visual Studio integration, etc.